# Power BI "This dataset includes a dynamic data source. Since dynamic data sources aren’t refreshed in the Power BI service"

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, refresh

Issue with PowerBi service failed

Dataset includes a dynamic data source. Since dynamic data sources aren't refreshed in the Power BI service, this dataset won't be refreshed. Learn more: https://aka.ms/dynamic-data-sources.

How to divide this url to basic , relative and query. *Note* there is a variable called VarDate included.

= Web.BrowserContents("https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=USD&date=" & VarDate & "#table-section")

Thanks in advance!

Tried the relative path method but I think I'm splitting it up incorrectly?

```
= Web.BrowserContents(
"https://www.xe.com/currencytables/",
[
RelativePath = "?from=USD&date=",
Query =  [VarDate] & "#table-section")
])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 mistakes in the code: one extra parenthesis and use of & incorrect in RelativePath.

Here's the corrected code:

```
= Web.BrowserContents(
    "https://www.xe.com/currencytables/",
    [
        RelativePath = "?from=USD&date=" & [VarDate] & "#table-section"
    ]
)
```

Comment: Hi Vio, thanks for your response! 

I've tested this out, however there seems to be an issue with the variable? This is the error message that I receive: 

 "Expression.Error: There is an unknown identifier. Did you use the [field] shorthand for a _[field] outside of an 'each' expression?"

Is there something else that I'm missing?